# Is it possible to search for messages with a matching substring in body and also a matching date?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I would like to, in a single request, get a list of messages filtered by date and by content in the body (if it's possible, of course).

I'm perfectly able to receive an ok response (200) from the following endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@company.com/messages?search="body:substring"
```

However, this gives me a broad response, since I'm interested only in cases between a specific week. Also, [it's impossible to use a **filter** parameter along with the **search** one.](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/graph/query-parameters#search-parameter)

Then, in regard to the date filter, I could use:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@company.com/messages?$filter=(sentDateTime ge 2000-01-01) and (sentDateTime le 2100-01-01)
```

The problem is: I cannot filter the body as well, since I receive an error 400 - 'Bad Request: Invalid filter clause':

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@company.com/messages?$filter=contains(body, substring)
```

Right now, my work around is: I request all the messages from *user@company.com* regarding a specific week, and after receiving that response, I locally filter the body in my machine. This works, but is not as fast as a compound request.

Answer (score 0):

You can include specific a date restriction within your KQL Search eg

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$search="(sent>=2019-01-01 AND sent<=2019-02-01) AND (body:asx)"
```

That should yield better performance then a filter